# Why helicopter don't go back?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, atmospheric-science

Why a helicopter stays at same place with respect to earth while floating in air despite of rotation of earth?

Answer (score 3):

The air is moving along with the Earth, plus or minus a few km/h (which manifests itself as the wind speed).